# How to get the value of session

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-variables, session-cookies

how to get the value from home.php and deliver it to 1home.php using SESSION. I want 1home.php get the value of home.php every i change the value of it.

```
session_start();
<form method="post" action="1home.php">
    <label id="checkinD">
            <h3>Day</h3>
                <Input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="number" min="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_today"]; ?>" max="<?php echo $_SESSION["day_count"]; ?>" required />
            </label>
</form>
session_start();
<form method="post"  action="2home.php" onsubmit="return validate()">
<label id="checkinD">
                    <h3>Day</h3>
                        <Input id="chiD" name="chiD" type="text" value = " 
<?php echo $chiD; ?>"  readonly />
            </label>
```

Comment: Have you heard of Google? Type in: "send session to another page php" and you have your Solution

Answer (score 1):

In first page were you have values

```
session_start();


$_SESSION["yourValue1"] = $yourValue1;
$_SESSION["yourValue2"] = $yourValue2;
```

in second page were you want to get them

```
session_start();

echo "your yourValue1 value is " . $_SESSION["yourValue1"] . ".<br>";
echo "your yourValue2 value is " . $_SESSION["yourValue2"] . ".";
```

Comment: ill try that one already but my problem is why isnt change when i change the value from form1??? why??